# Display sibling categories on category page

Tags: categories, taxonomy, terms

I have a category page, how do i display this category sibling categories on this  page as well? I know how to display children categories:

```
<ul class="slider-container-list sub-categories-block front-categories-block front-categories-scroll">
        <?php
            $term = get_queried_object();
            $children = get_terms( $term->taxonomy, array(
                    'parent'    => $term->term_id,
                    'hide_empty' => false
            ) );
            if ( $children ) {
                    foreach( $children as $subcat ){
                            echo '<li class="category-thumbnail-item"><a class="category-thumbnail" href="' . esc_url(get_term_link($subcat, $subcat->taxonomy)) . '">';
                            echo '<div class="category-thumbnail-image"><img src="' . z_taxonomy_image_url($subcat->term_id, 'medium'). '" data-pin-nopin="true" alt="'. $subcat->name .' Sub Category Image"> </div>';
                            echo '<div class="category-title">' . $subcat->name . '</div></a></li>';
                    }
            }
            ?>
         </ul>
```

Now i am trying to figure out how to display siblings... Should i call parent ID and children after? I think i need to get term_id somehow, i am sure i am missing something:(

```
             <ul class="slider-container-list sub-categories-block front-categories-block front-categories-scroll">
             <?php
             $term_id = 10;
             $taxonomy_name = 'products';
             $termchildren = get_term_children( $term_id, $taxonomy_name );

                 if ( $termchildren ) {
                         foreach ( $termchildren as $child ){
                                 echo '<li class="category-thumbnail-item"><a class="category-thumbnail" href="' . esc_url(get_term_link($child, $child->taxonomy)) . '">';
                                 echo '<div class="category-thumbnail-image"><img src="' . z_taxonomy_image_url($child->term_id, 'medium'). '" data-pin-nopin="true" alt="'. $child->name .' Sub Category Image"> </div>';
                                 echo '<div class="category-title">' . $child->name . '</div></a></li>';
                         }
                 }
                 ?>
                </ul>
```

i assume, but how i exclude existing category i am on from this list. Hope it makes sense:) Please help anyone?

**UPDATE:** So i found the solution:

```
<ul class="slider-container-list sub-categories-block front-categories-block front-categories-scroll">
<?php
$term = get_queried_object();
$children = get_terms( $term->taxonomy, array(
        'parent'    => $term->term_id,
        'hide_empty' => false
) );
if ( $children ) {
        foreach( $children as $subcat ){
                echo '<li class="category-thumbnail-item"><a class="category-thumbnail" href="' . esc_url(get_term_link($subcat, $subcat->taxonomy)) . '">';
                echo '<div class="category-thumbnail-image"><img src="' . z_taxonomy_image_url($subcat->term_id, 'medium'). '" data-pin-nopin="true" alt="'. $subcat->name .' Sub Category Image"> </div>';
                echo '<div class="category-title">' . $subcat->name . '</div></a></li>';
        }
}
?>
</ul>
<ul class="slider-container-list sub-categories-block front-categories-block front-categories-scroll">
 <?php
     $term = get_queried_object();
     $siblings = get_terms( $term->taxonomy, array(
         'parent'    => $term->parent,
         'taxonomy'   => $taxonomy_name,
         'exclude'    => array( $current_term->term_id ),
         'hide_empty' => false,
     ) );
     if ( $siblings ) {
             foreach( $siblings as $sibling ){
                     echo '<li class="category-thumbnail-item"><a class="category-thumbnail" href="' . esc_url(get_term_link($sibling, $sibling->taxonomy)) . '">';
                     echo '<div class="category-thumbnail-image"><img src="' . z_taxonomy_image_url($sibling->term_id, 'medium'). '" data-pin-nopin="true" alt="'. $sibling->name .' Sub Category Image"> </div>';
                     echo '<div class="category-title">' . $sibling->name . '</div></a></li>';
             }
     }
     ?>
    </ul>
```

I am able to display siblings here, but now my challenge is to

1. Exclude the existing category, that i am on.
2. And not to display siblings for the top parent categories

Fun fun!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have a category page, how do i display this category sibling
> categories on this page as well? I know how to display children
> categories

> I think i need to get term_id somehow

On a term archive page, e.g. at `example.com/category/foo/` (for the default `category` taxonomy),

1. You can use [`get_queried_object()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_queried_object/) to retrieve the term *object* for the term being queried (`foo` in the above sample URL).

   ```php
   $term = get_queried_object();
   $term_id = $term->term_id;
   ```
2. You can use [`get_queried_object_id()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_queried_object_id/) to retrieve just the term *ID* of the term being queried.

   ```php
   $term_id = get_queried_object_id();
   ```

Now as for retrieving term's siblings, you can use [`get_terms()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/) just like you did when retrieving the term's children. So for example, for the term being queried (or simply put, the current term),

```php
$taxonomy_name = 'products';

// Get the full term object/data.
$current_term = get_queried_object();

// Get the term's direct children.
// **Use 'child_of' instead of 'parent' to retrieve direct and non-direct children.
$children = get_terms( array(
    'taxonomy'   => $taxonomy_name,
    'parent'     => $current_term->term_id,
    'hide_empty' => false,
) );

// Display the children.
if ( ! empty( $children ) ) {
    echo "<h3>Children of $current_term->name</h3>";
    echo '<ul>';

    foreach ( $children as $child ) {
        echo "<li>$child->name</li>";
    }

    echo '</ul>';
}

// Get the term's direct siblings.
$siblings = get_terms( array(
    'taxonomy'   => $taxonomy_name,
    'parent'     => $current_term->parent,
    'exclude'    => array( $current_term->term_id ),
    'hide_empty' => false,
) );

// Display the siblings.
if ( ! empty( $siblings ) ) {
    echo "<h3>Siblings of $current_term->name</h3>";
    echo '<ul>';

    foreach ( $siblings as $sibling ) {
        echo "<li>$sibling->name</li>";
    }

    echo '</ul>';
}
```

And if you want to use [`get_term_children()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_term_children/), note that it retrieves all *direct and non-direct* children (just like `get_terms()` if `child_of` is used), and the function returns an *array of term **ID***s, hence in your `foreach`, you can use [`get_term()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_term/) to get the full term object/data.

```php
$term_id = get_queried_object_id(); // or just use a specific term ID, if you want to
$termchildren = get_term_children( $term_id, $taxonomy_name );

foreach ( $termchildren as $child_id ) {
    $child = get_term( $child_id );
    // ... your code.
}
```

> how i exclude existing category i am on from this list

- If you use `get_terms()`, you can use the `exclude` arg like you can see in my example above.
- If you use `get_term_children()`, then you can use `continue` like so: (but that's just an example; you can use `array_filter()` to filter the `$termchildren` array *before* looping through the items, if you want to)

  ```php
  foreach ( $termchildren as $child_id ) {
      if ( (int) $child_id === (int) $term_id ) {
          continue;
      }

      $child = get_term( $child_id );
      // ... your code.
  }
  ```

Comment: Please look at the answer above:) Updated my post. And i found solution for #2, adding class to the top category, and using css to remove it: `add_filter( 'body_class', 'custom_cat_archiev_class' );
function custom_cat_archiev_class( $classes ) {
 if ( is_category() ) {
 $cat = get_queried_object();
 $ancestors = get_ancestors( $cat->term_id, 'category', 'taxonomy' );
 $classes[] = 'category-level-' . ( count( $ancestors ) + 1 );
}
return $classes;
}`

Comment: So i am still looking for solution for #1. Thanks!

Comment: Well, did my answer answered your main question - how to retrieve and display the term's siblings? And when you said, "exclude existing category i am on from this list", I actually thought something like, if you're on category 10, you wanted 10 to be *removed from the array* (of terms)? If not, or if you're referring to *another* taxonomy, then that should be asked in a separate post. Or if you're actually looking for CSS solution/help, then Stack Overflow is better suited for that.

Comment: Also, if you look at the `get_terms()` [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/), it stated that the 2nd parameter is *deprecated* and it also says, "*Since 4.5.0, taxonomies should be passed via the ‘taxonomy’ argument in the `$args` array:*", e.g. `$terms = get_terms( array( 'taxonomy' => 'products', 'parent' => 10, 'hide_empty' => false ) );`, just like in my examples. :-) So always use the `get_terms( <args array> )` format and **not** `get_terms( <taxonomy>, <args array> )`, unless of course if you're still using WordPress prior to v4.5.0 ..

Comment: Thank you Sally i did not know that! Appreciate your help!

Comment: This worked great for me when I needed to display sibling categories for WooCommerce product categories. All I had to do was change the `$taxonomy_name = 'products';` to `$taxonomy_name = 'product_cat';`. Thanks @SallyCJ!

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul class="display-children-block slider-container-list sub-categories-block front-categories-block front-categories-scroll">
<?php
$term = get_queried_object();
$children = get_terms( $term->taxonomy, array(
'parent'    => $term->term_id,
'hide_empty' => false
) );
if ( $children ) {
foreach( $children as $subcat ){
        echo '<li class="category-thumbnail-item"><a class="category-thumbnail" href="' . esc_url(get_term_link($subcat, $subcat->taxonomy)) . '">';
        echo '<div class="category-thumbnail-image"><img src="' . z_taxonomy_image_url($subcat->term_id, 'medium'). '" data-pin-nopin="true" alt="'. $subcat->name .' Sub Category Image"> </div>';
        echo '<div class="category-title">' . $subcat->name . '</div></a></li>';
}
}
?>
</ul>
<ul class="display-siblings-block slider-container-list sub-categories-block front-categories-block front-categories-scroll">
    <?php
$term = get_queried_object();
$siblings = get_terms( $term->taxonomy, array(
 'parent'    => $term->parent,
   'taxonomy'   => $taxonomy_name,
   'exclude'    => array( $term->term_id ),
   'hide_empty' => false,
) );

if ( $siblings ) {
     foreach( $siblings as $sibling ){
             echo '<li class="category-thumbnail-item"><a class="category-thumbnail" href="' . esc_url(get_term_link($sibling, $sibling->taxonomy)) . '">';
             echo '<div class="category-thumbnail-image"><img src="' . z_taxonomy_image_url($sibling->term_id, 'medium'). '" data-pin-nopin="true" alt="'. $sibling->name .' Sub Category Image"> </div>';
             echo '<div class="category-title">' . $sibling->name . '</div></a></li>';
     }
}
?>
</ul>
```

This is what i did for all of it and it works!

Also this snippet add class to the :

```
add_filter( 'body_class', 'custom_cat_archiev_class' );
function custom_cat_archiev_class( $classes ) {
    if ( is_category() ) {
        $cat = get_queried_object();
        $ancestors = get_ancestors( $cat->term_id, 'category', 'taxonomy' );
        $classes[] = 'category-level-' . ( count( $ancestors ) + 1 );
    }
    return $classes;
}
```

And i am using css to remove siblings from top level Categories.

Honestly i think i can make it cleaner without classes and css. But i am not sure how!